# how to get id referred domain data when reference table name in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

**Hi my project is based on hibernate project.**

here my tables are Book,Category book contain foreign key of category _id category contain

*id,name,code*

my need is when i search by category_name it should return all book contain that category name.

i tried below query

```
  select * from Book where Category_id=(select * from Category where name='name')
```

But the code not supported by hibernate

Someone know please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

`where Category_id in` should be used and also in the sub query

```
(select category_id from Category where name='name')
```

HQL: something like below(remember that category_id heree is not the column name, it is the property name in the Entity)

```
select book from Book book where Category_id in (select cat.category_id from Category cat where name='name')
```

Comment: how does in case of hibernate

Comment: Did you ask about the HQL query?